# Call from Outlook Email Numbers

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, ms-office, office-addins

I have a softphone. Now, I want to create an outlook addin that enables users to call directly from numbers inside outlook email. Is that possible? Can I accomplish this using Office Apps  or Addin ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the softphone you are using. If it is web based and has a web API to access it you could use an App for Office.  If it is software on the computer itself it may be possible with an add-in but not with an App for Office.